# Spring API consumed by Webapp and mobile app

Tags: spring-boot, mobile, ionic-framework, spring-security, cors

I have a webapplication developped with Angular 2 and a Rest API developped with Springboot.

```
Mme Michu ---> WebApp (Angular 2 - Known origin) ---> API (Springboot CORS)
```

I configured CORS between the webapp and the API and it works fine.

Here is how my CORSFilter is implemented

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter{

public SimpleCORSFilter () {
    super();
}

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

private String[] acao;

@Override
public final void doFilter(final ServletRequest req, final ServletResponse res, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    acao = environment.getProperty("access-control-allow-origin").split(",");

    final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

    String origin = request.getHeader("Origin");

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", Arrays.asList(acao).contains(origin)?origin:"" );

    // without this header jquery.ajax calls returns 401 even after successful login and SSESSIONID being succesfully stored.
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Authorization, Origin, Content-Type, Version");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Authorization, Origin, Content-Type");


    if(!request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

@Override
public void destroy() {

}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    acao = environment.getProperty("access-control-allow-origin").split(",");
}
```

}

The problem is that I need a new mobile application (developped with ionic) to interact with the API.

```
Mme Michu --> MobileApp (Unknown origin) ---> API (Springboot CORS)
```

Will the CORS policy block the request from the mobile app ? 
How can I authorize requests from the mobile application since I can't know the 'origin' of the mobile app ?

Any advice is welcome ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The origin is the domain issuing the request to the api, if your webapp's domain is example.com, the requests will have example.com as origin. When a resource is blocked because of the origin, it is a client side security mechanism that is blocking the response (the server is not aware of it). You don't how Ionic works but i don't think it implements this kind of mechanism (except for progressive web application maybe).

The server is responsible for reporting the allowed origins. The web browser is responsible for enforcing that requests are only sent from allowed domains.

Comment: I don't understand your answer... CORS filter is server sided so how a client (mobile app) can provide a granted origin ?

Comment: CORS headers are sent by your server, it is right, but it is not the server that is blocking when the origin does not match the server. Do the test with different origin and you will see that the server is sending a response back that is blocked by the client (your browser) . The server is responsible for reporting the allowed origins. The web browser is responsible for enforcing that requests are only sent from allowed domains.

Comment: Super! i'll give it a try ! 
Merci ;)